# what are the loudest bass strings?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I have a 38" 5 string bass and I don't have an amp. I know amps are almost equal to the price of strings, but

1. I cannot whatsoever play a 100 gauge B string or high E,
2. I don't want to tune up an octave because I have a guitar,
3. Can I tune bass up 4-5 steps?

Comment: I’m pretty confused. Are you asking if you can get some type of bass strings that will make it so you don’t need an amp? No strings can replace an amp. Strings generally are all the same volume.

Comment: It's not integral to the question, but the size of a bass is typically measured by scale length, not total length, and 38" is a highly unusual scale length for a bass.  So, I don't really know what size your bass is.

Comment: This question isn't making much sense. Loud strings? un-amplified there won't be a lot of difference if any between makes (product recommendation is off-side here anyway).Low B with .100 isn't usual - .125 is. High E - there isn't a high E on bass. You can tune up as much as you like, but the gauge of strings already on will determine when the neck snaps. Please make the question clearer. And - standard bass strings are ~34", not sure where 38" comes in. Very mixed up.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes.  It seems clear to me that the problem OP is trying to solve is that he wants his electric bass to be louder without an amp, and his idea to achieve this is select louder strings and possibly tune up a little.  You might think this is not a good idea- I agree- but then put that in your answer, instead of closing the question.

Comment: @Edward re-tuning the strings by a fourth up can increase the tension by a lot, possibly to a range that is dangerous for the instrument. It is irresponsible to give an advice when we are uncertain what is the scale, what are the string gauges and how they are tuned.

Comment: @user1079505 Is this in response to my answer?  Regardless of the scale length, tuning up a fourth only requires moving the strings over by 1.  There is nothing irresponsible about recommending that.

Comment: @Edward Even though I didn’t VTC, I agree that when a question is as confusing as this one, “needs details or clarity” is a valid close reason. The asker can simply edit to explain what they are actually asking and then it can be reopened.

Comment: For this question to make sense it needs to be clarified if the instrument really has extended scale of 38", how is it tuned and what are the string gauges.

Answer (score 1):

The electric bass guitar is not an acoustic instrument.  I will answer your question, but not before saying that you should absolutely NOT buy strings based on their acoustic volume.  Strings don't affect the volume of the instrument much at all.  **Get an amp before all else.**

If you want to play a bass without an amp, you should be using an acoustic bass.

Besides that, if you're willing to play with a pick, that will be much louder than your fingers.

Strings are low down on the list on things that could make the instrument louder.

That said, the main things that would make a set of strings loud are 1) weight and 2) brightness.

Weight can be had simply by buying a heavier set of strings.  Most companies will sell a set in "medium", "light", etc.  Buying the next heavier set will make the body of the instrument vibrate a little bit more intensely, thus increasing volume.  **I do not advise getting volume like this because it affects playability much more than volume.**  It also can reduce the brightness of the strings, which would mostly negate any volume benefits you got.

Brightness can be had by using roundwound stainless steel strings.  These will be louder in the high frequencies, which your ear is more sensitive to, and thus will sound louder.  **I do not advise getting volume like this because the "meat" of the bass tone is in the bass frequencies, and a brighter tone will not let you hear the bass frequencies any better.**

You can tune your bass up, with the right strings.  Though BEADG is the most common tuning for a 5-string bass, EADGC is also common.  You're effectively moving the EADG strings over one, and then adding a C string at the top.  To do this properly, you will need to replace the nut on your instrument with one that has smaller slots for the strings.  You get a slight loudness increase just by playing in a higher register, but your EADG strings don't actually get any louder.  You just have the option to play on the ADGC strings instead.